# Include image in solution with code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm saving an image in the Contents folder of my MVC project. The image is succesfully saved in the correct path, but it's not included in my project. Here is how I save it:

```
var uploadedFile = this.Request.Files[0];
if (uploadedFile.ContentLength != 0)
{
    string savedFileName = Server.MapPath("..") + "\\Content\\images\\myImages\\" + theId + ".jpg";
    uploadedFile.SaveAs(savedFileName);
}
```

It can't be seen in my solution. How to include it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the file is in the same folder, doesn't include it in the project. But you can still access it.

Use the "Show All Files" button (at the top of the solution explorer). This will show all hidden files.

Then richtclick on the file and select "Include in Project" if you really want to include the file in the project.

**EDIT**
The "Include in project" function includes a reference to the file in your project file (projectname.csproj in the root of your project). You might possibly be able to do the same with your own code (it's an XML file), but when you deploy the site, that .csproj file is NOT included (nor is it needed).

You might want to explain why you want to add that user-uploaded file to the project definition. The uploaded file is still available for download, even if it isn't registered in some .csproj file.